# are there books of texts made by combining similar hadiths, avoiding repetitions?

Tags: hadith

as can be seen in https://sunnah.com/search?q=divorce there are many hadiths that are similar and have differing parts in text and in isnad.

they are difficult to read. similar hadiths could be joined together into one text with references from above every mentioned thesis, as in wikipedia.

are there such books of texts made by joining similar hadiths?

for example there i see 2 similar hadiths: https://sunnah.com/urn/512410 and https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi:1192 . all informations available in them could be combined into one text.

Comment: What is joined hadith? Explain what you mean!

Comment: @Medi1Saif look at example of 2 similar hadiths i have shown

Comment: These are two different ahadith with differences in both narrator chains and wording from two different sources however it is clear that one has a full chain while the other is mursal hadith. Of course they will be different.

Answer (score 1):

**A try to explain the appearance and necessity of sanad and repetition in the sources**

To try to help you understand the topic:

The hadith sources like al-Muwatta', the Sahih's (of for example al-Bukhari, Muslim, ibn Hebban, ibn Khozaimah. I don't know of any other author claiming to have gathered Sahih hadith or naming his book Sahih), the Sunan books (of for example abu Dawod, ibn Majah, an-Nasa-i, a-Darimi etc.), the Musnads (Ahamad, 'Abdurrazaq, al-Bazzar, Abu Ya'ala, ibn abi Shayabah etc.) and Jami' at-Tirmidhi etc.  were never intended for laymen, so they would never for example gather all hadith with the same content as chosen in your example in one single quote.
However if you check these books you'll find repetitions of more or less the same content with a difference in the narrator chains. But you must be aware that each scholar had his own structure, organization and layout of his hadith compilation. And one could say almost each book was compiled to fulfill a specific goal.

Why did these authors not do this:
First sanad is an evidence, if a person verifies the sanad he/she can check whether or not this hadith is reliable at least based on the narrator chain .
Secondly when hadith fabrication started during the era of Tabi'iyn people started requesting a sanad.
Further scholars of this time regarded each version of a hadith or combination of a sanad and a content (with exact wording) as a single hadith therefore you may hear that al-Bukhari memorized more than 600.000 hadith from which he has chosen his 7000+ in the Sahih (which includes repetitions and without these repetitions the content is less than 3000).

**Books that seem to fit or are close to what you are looking for**

Later when hadith sciences were established and hadith was categorized in different categories (sahih, hassan, da'if, madu') and the terminology was rather established. It became easier to refer to books with the full source and/or add a qualification.  Therefore scholars started writing books that are also intended for laymen which excluded the full narrator chain and refer to the different sources of a specific narration that have the same or similar content (I guess this is the closest to what you seem to be looking for):

- Riyadh as-Saliheen رياض الصالحين of imam [an-Nawawi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al-Nawawi). According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Meadows_of_the_Righteous):

> The hadith by al-Nawawī belongs to the category of canonical Arabic collections of Islamic morals, acts of worship, and manners, which are attributed to Muhammad by Muslim scholars but not found in the Quran.

- The 40 hadiths الأربعون النووية of imam an-Nawawi. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al-Nawawi%27s_Forty_Hadith):

> "In putting together this collection, it was the author’s explicit aim that “each hadith is a great fundament (qāʿida ʿaẓīma) of the religion, described by the religious scholars as being ‘the axis of Islam’ or ‘the half of Islam’ or ‘the third of it’ or the like, and to make it a rule that these forty hadith be classified as sound"

- Jami' al-'Uloom wal-Hikam جامع العلوم والحكم of [ibn Rajab al-Hanbali](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ibn_Rajab) (which includes the 40 ahadith of imam an-Nawawi and adds a few more to complete 50 essential ahadith which ibn Rajab further commented)
- [Mishakt al-Masabih](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mishkat_al-Masabih) مشكاة المصابيح of at-Tabrizi محمد الخطيب التبريزي which includes more than 5000 hadith and is a big collection of rather reliable ahadith with a qualification of the author and which is a compendium of an early book called [Masabih as-Sunnah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Masabih_al-Sunnah) of imam al-Baghawi. This book was commented by scholars like ibn hajar and 'Ali al-Qari.
- [Majma' az-Zawaid](http://Majma%20al-Zawa%27id) of al-Haythami in which he compiled hadith from sources other than the so called 6 sahihs namely: the three works of at Tabarani, Musnad Ahmad, Musnad al-Bazzar and Musnad abu Ya'ala.
- At-Targheeb wa at-Tarheeb الترغيب والترهيب of imam al-Mundhiri with about 1000 hadith. I recall this book having some repetitions of variations of same or similar content. According [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/At-Targhib_wat-Tarhib):

> The author of the book basically compiled those Hadiths which are dealing with virtues of various good deeds and warning to avoid some Evil Deeds.

All the above sources are widely known and at least one of them would be part of common knowledge or a private library if people can afford buying these books. However none of them is free from da'if narrations.
In case of the four first mentioned books the author would share the information of sources of a hadith narrative, however if one would do a deeper research in cases one may find out that the wording of the author is from a specific source while the wording in other sources might be different or missing or adding words. For example compare:

> On the authority of Abu Muhammad al-Hasan ibn Ali ibn Abee Talib (may Allah be pleased with him), the grandson of the Messenger of Allah (peace and blessings of Allah be upon him), and the one much loved by him, who said:
> I memorised from the Messenger of Allah (peace and blessings of Allah be upon him): “Leave that which makes you doubt for that which does not make you doubt.”
> [At-Tirmidhi] [An-Nasai]

At-Tirmidhi said that it was a good and sound (hasan saheeh) hadeeth. ([40 hadith of an-Nawawi](https://sunnah.com/nawawi40:11))

with the version from [Jami' at-Tirmidhi](https://sunnah.com/urn/727030) and that of [Sunan an-Nasa-i](https://sunnah.com/nasai:5711).

In a similar why some authors wrote books on specific topic like:

- [Bulugh al-Maraam min adilati al-Ahkam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulugh_al-Maram) بلوغ المرام من أدلة الأحكام of ibn Hajar on ahadith on fiqh topics. The book  includes 1596 hadith and the author might point at differences in the wording of different variations of a hadith and their impact.

Some scholars actually started doing the same with the sources you may find summarized versions of Sahih al-Bukhari which have no sanad or no repetition or neither of both.
[Muhammad Fu'ad 'Abudlbaqi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muhammad_Fuad_Abdul_Baqi) محمد فؤاد عبد الباقي -among many other books of hadith- published a book he called al-Lu'lu' wal Marjan fima itafaqa 'alayhi a-Shaykhan "[اللؤلؤ والمرجان فيما اتفق عليه الشيخان](https://al-maktaba.org/book/10619)" which includes around 2000 ahadith on which the authors of both Sahih's imam al-Bukhari and imam Muslim agreed in the meaning ibn Hajar defined: "same narrator chain, even with difference in wording". He chose the wording of al-Bukhari of a hadith that is the closest to that of Muslim (this means the hadith of al-Bukhari might not strictly be that on which he "agreed" with Muslim in the narrator chain) and used the arrangement/order of Muslim and the choice of Chapter titles of imam an-Nawawi in his commentary on Sahih Muslim.